# I want to add firebase into my flutter app but when i set it up, am having a lot of errors in VS Code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i followed this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnpGU8vj7TI in order to set firebase with flutter,and after doing exactly as the guy did am having a lot of errors showing in my terminal when I try to run the **main.dart** file

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding().ensureVisualUpdate();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(My_pp());
}

class My_pp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return My_ppstate();
  }
}

class My_ppstate extends State<My_pp> {
  
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('hello'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(50, 255, 255, 5),
        ),
       
            
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the errors are

> lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:led_blink/main.dart'.
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' as ui;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /D:/flutter_windows_2.0.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

this is the flutter doctor --verbose results:
[image]
the build.gradle from the android folder
[image]
the build.gradle from the app folder
[image]

Comment: first try running `flutter clean` and then add your `flutter doctor --verbose` results to your question. It's a bit difficult to help with the amount of information you've given, but I'll see what I can do after we get the doctor's results (and possibly a bit more of your code).

Comment: i added what u requested and am sorry for the late reply

Comment: With the information that you've given, I'm going to assume that this is not a problem with your firebase setup. I followed the tutorial and it worked for me, but I am not on windows. Due to the `Error: Not found:` errors, I am going to assume that the issue lies in the setup of your Flutter project (may want to `flutter create` again) or in the flutter SDK you have installed. Try reinstalling flutter and/or recreating the project.

Comment: i reinstalled everything but the problem still the same.. i guess i'll use android studio instead,thank u for ur time anyways!!